# Using the TwoLineListItem component

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-view

I have to create a list whose list items have 2 lines of text. I started building a custom list item, but then I discovered the `TwoLineListItem` component. I wrote this code:

```
pageFilterResultView=new TwoLineListItem(containerActivity);
pageFilterResultView.getText1().setText("Test");
```

However, `getText1` returns null, and the second line throws a `NullPointerException`. So I thought I need to use an inflated layout instead of a constructor. The [TwoLineListItem documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TwoLineListItem.html) specifies I can use the `android.R.layout.two_line_list_item` resource for the layout, so I changed the code to:

```
LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)containerActivity.
        getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
pageFilterResultView=(TwoLineListItem)inflater.inflate(android.R.
        layout.two_line_list_item,null);
pageFilterResultView.getText1().setText("Test");
```

However, this throws a `ClassCastException` because the layout is actually a `LinearLayout`. `TwoLineListItem` inherits from `RelativeLayout`, so I can't even cast the layout to a higher class in the hierarchy.

So the question is: How do I use `TwoLineListItem` correctly? Do I have to create my own custom layout for it? If so, what's the point of this component if I still have to do all the work of creating a list item by myself?

Comment: put your log cat error ..........

Comment: I know why the errors are occurring, this is not the issue. I want to know what's the right way of using this component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I use TwoLineListItem correctly?

The `TwoLineListItem` widget is a facade over two `TextViews` that have to be provided by you. To use the `TwoLineListItem` in a `ListView`'s row you'll need a row layout where you have the `TwoLineListItem` widget with two(at least) `TextView` children with specific ids(`android.R.id.text1` and `android.R.id.text2`). Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TwoLineListItem xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@android:id/text1"/>

</TwoLineListItem>
```

Then you can use it in the `getView()` method like you did:

```
pageFilterResultView=(TwoLineListItem)inflater.inflate(R.layout.the_layout_file_above,null);
pageFilterResultView.getText1().setText("Test");
```

Of course you have the possibility of using an included layout file as the child of the `TwoLineListItem`(as long as you have the two `TextViews` with the required ids):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TwoLineListItem xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <!-- the android version of the two line layout -->
    <include layout="@android:layout/two_line_list_item" />

</TwoLineListItem>
```

but this just increases the layout depth and should be avoided.

> If so, what's the point of this component if I still have to do all
>   the work of creating a list item by myself?

Judging by the fact that you can't use this widget programmatically, I don't see the need for this component either.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the `include layout=...` option, but you say it should be avoided, so I think I'll use my own component after all...

Comment: @user940016 It should be avoided from my point of view because if you don't use `merge` in the included layout then you'll have an extra useless `ViewGroup` between the content and the `TwoLineListItem` widget.

Answer (score -1):

put your layout code inside try catch block with ClassCastException it will works fine my Friend . .....

Comment: This is nonsense! How can I get an instance of the component if what I get from the inflation is not of the right type?